# Lodash: Convert array with duplicate values to object with number of repeated occurrences

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js, lodash

Here is my array:

```
['California','Texas','Texas','Texas','New York','Missouri','New Mexico','California']
```

Is there a way in lodash to convert it to an object with a count of repeated occurrences like this:

```
[
    {'name':'California', 'count':2},
    {'name':'Texas', 'count':3},
    {'name':'New York', 'count':1},
    {'name':'Missouri', 'count':1},
    {'name':'New Mexico', 'count':1},
]
```

I have tried many combinations but have not been successful. Docs: https://lodash.com/docs#countBy

Comment: What have you tried? Seems to me that `countBy` works, you just have to slightly modify the result after it's done

Comment: Since you only have two properties maybe it would work better as `{California: 2, Texas: 3}` -- just a suggestion

Comment: @ExplosionPills this is exactly what `countBy` produces if you call it with no other arguments than the data in this post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just map the result of `_.countBy`.

```js
var array = ['California','Texas','Texas','Texas','New York','Missouri','New Mexico','California'],
    count = _.countBy(array),
    result = _.map(count, (v, k) => ({ name: k, count: v }));

console.log(count);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Combined with `_.chain`

```js
var array = ['California','Texas','Texas','Texas','New York','Missouri','New Mexico','California'],
    count = _
        .chain(array)
        .countBy()
        .map((v, k) => ({ name: k, count: v }));

console.log(count);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you `_.chain` the calls, it'd be ever so slightly more performant, since you don't need the interim values. It makes the code look a bit tidier, too (again - no interim values). `_.reduce` might be a bit more idiomatic for this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for a solution with Lodash! Just a heads up, the variables 'k' and 'v' above need to switch. Otherwise it says: { name:3, count:'Texas' }

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `reduce()`

```js
var ar = ['California','Texas','Texas','Texas','New York','Missouri','New Mexico','California'];

var obj = {}
var result = ar.reduce(function(r, e) {
  if(!obj[e]) {
    obj[e] = {name: e, count: 0};
    r.push(obj[e])
  }
  obj[e].count++;
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is a built-in function to achieve it, but you can do it using standard method.

```
var arr = ['California', 'Texas', 'Texas', 'Texas', 'New York', 'Missouri', 'New Mexico', 'California'];
var obj = [];

arr.forEach(a => {
    var b = obj.find(b => b.name == a);
    if(!b){
        obj.push({
            name: a,
            count: 1
        });
    }else{
        b.count++;
    }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
```

Comment: You can use `find` instead of `filter`. It more precisely what you want.

Comment: @Vld Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you said there's the countBy function for that, you have to map the result to set the format as required:

```
var result = _( array )
  .countBy( )
  .map( ( key, value ) => ( { name: key, count: value } ) )
  .value( )

console.log( result );
```

Comment: OP already mentioned it. Also, you don't need the second parameter - it defaults to the same.

Comment: right, I didn't noticed, I'll update the answer then

Answer (score 0):

In plain Javascript, you could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for it.

```js
var data = ['toString', 'California', 'Texas', 'Texas', 'Texas', 'New York', 'Missouri', 'New Mexico', 'California'],
    count = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a]) {
        this[a] = { name: a, count: 0 };
        count.push(this[a]);
    }
    this[a].count++;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(count)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Version with `{}`

```js
var data = ['toString', 'California', 'Texas', 'Texas', 'Texas', 'New York', 'Missouri', 'New Mexico', 'California'],
    count = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a]) {
        this[a] = { name: a, count: 0 };
        count.push(this[a]);
    }
    this[a].count++;
}, {}); // no Object.create(null)!

console.log(count)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: It would be better if you join your answers or delete this one.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `Object.create(null)` and not just `{}`

Comment: @NenadVracar, you could count over `toString` and that would not go without a really empty object.

Comment: @NinaScholz The only property of an object created with `{}` is `__proto__`. Function `toString` is actually the property of `{}.__proto__.constructor.prototype`.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer171, please watch the difference of example one and two. keep an eye on `toString`.

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS in just two lines.

```js
var arr = ['California','Texas','Texas','Texas','New York','Missouri','New Mexico','California'],
    lut = arr.reduce((p,c) => p[c] ? (p[c]++ ,p) : (p[c] = 1, p),{});
 result = Object.keys(lut).map(k => ({name:k,count:lut[k]}));
console.log(result);
```